# normalizr v3 and JSON api

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I want to normalise the responses I receive from an API. A typical response could look something like this:

```
// Get all projects
{data:[
    {
        id: 1
        ...
        team:{
            data: {
                id:15
                ...
            }

        }
    },
    {
        id:2,
        ....
    },
    {
        id:3,
        ...
    }
]}
```

How do I write my schemas so that it removes the 'data' container?
Currently, my schema looks like:

```
export const project = new schema.Entity('projects', {
    team: team, // team omitted
},
{
    processStrategy: (value, parent, key) => parent.data
}
)

export const arrayOfProjects = new schema.Array(project)
```

And I am using it like:

```
const normalizedProjects = normalize(jsonResponse, arrayOfProjects)
```

*normalizedProjects* then looks like this:

```
{
    entities:{
        projects:{
            undefined:{
                0:{
                    team:{
                        data:{
                            id:15,
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                },
                1:{...},
                2:{...}.
                ...
                50:{...},
            }
        }
    },
    result:[] // length is 0
}
```

I'm not sure why the list of projects is contained in 'undefined', either?

Answer (score 1):

I also use json_api schema. 
How about like this?

```
const projectsSchema = new schema.Entity('projects', {}, {
  processStrategy: processStrategy
});

export const processStrategy = (value, parent, key) => {
  const attr = value.attributes;
  delete value.attributes;
  return { ...value, ...attr };
};

export const fetchProjectsSchema = {
  data: [projectsSchema]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of your entity schema that you want to have the `data` omitted (or anything else fundamentalyl *changed*) needs to include a [processStrategy](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#entitykey-definition---options--) that you write to remove or change any data. (see more examples in the [tests](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/b51f9eedc78f37e6f183dedbd8f3c062110fdfdd/src/schemas/__tests__/Entity.test.js#L65-L99))

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have tried that now but I can't seem to do anything to remove the 'undefined' object parenting whatever I am returning from the processStrategy function, which looks like processStrategy: (value, parent, key) => parent.data;.
Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: If you could show some code, what you're doing might be a lot more clear.

Comment: Edited the original question to slim the data down and show what I'm doing for the process strategy.

Comment: You're using a JSONAPI schema as in jsonapi.org? (Not just a "json api"). So, Normalizr is not really good for JSONAPI. There was a fork of Normalizr that attempted to work well with it, but I'm not sure if it went anywhere https://github.com/prenaudin/normalize-json-api